# Can Dart communicate / talk to Java?

Tags: dart

I have a Java web service (with some server side business logic) created with jsp and servlets. Is there any useful way to let Dart and Java communicate / talk to each other? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/

Http can be sent or received by most languages.

Answer (score 2):

A Dart client-side web application can indeed interact with server-side web services.

The language or platform that the server-side web services are written in and deployed on are unimportant as long as both sides support the protocols and data formats used to exchange messages.

Presumably your web service uses HTTP as the transport protocol and either XML or JSON as the data format. The article mentioned by @kpie should be a good starting point.